# Trouble Pushing to Deep Nested Array in MongoDb C# driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core

I am trying to push to a deeply nested array (2-deep) in Mongodb using the C# driver in .NET Core 2.

The code looks right, compiles fine and returns a successful response in Postman.   However, when I look for the new item in Compass, it doesn't exist.

I can push to the first array (Questions) no problem using LINQ, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with the element match method in the 2nd level.   I tried to find a way using LINQ, but couldn't find the right code.   I

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

**Rough schema:**

```
Quiz
{
   ObjectId Id { get; set;}
   List<Question> Questions { get; set;}
}

// 1st array - easy to push to

Question
{
   ObjectId Id { get; set;}
   string text { get; set;} 
   List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

// 2nd level - having trouble pushing to

Answer
{
   ObjectId Id { get; set;}
   string text { get; set;} 
}
```

**Code**

```
 public static ResponseMessage AddAnswer(string id, string questionId, Answer answer)
        {
            ResponseMessage result = new ResponseMessage()
            {
                Code = HttpStatusCode.Created,
                Message = "ANSWER_CREATED"
            };


            IMongoCollection<Quiz> col = DatabaseHelper.QuizCol;

            try
            {
                UpdateDefinition<Quiz> update = Builders<Quiz>.Update.Push("Questions.$[q].Answers", answer);
                col.UpdateOne<Quiz>(x => x.Id == ObjectId.Parse(id), update, new UpdateOptions
                {
                    ArrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>
                    {
                        new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument("q.Id", ObjectId.Parse(questionId))),
                    }
                });
                answer = DecorateAnswer(id, questionId, answer);
                result.Identifier = answer.Id.ToString();
                result.Resource = answer.Resource;
            }
            catch (MongoException ex)
            {
                result.Code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                result.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: That's `"q._id"` and not `"q.Id"`. The reason is that using the `BsonDocument` construction you are basically writing the BSON instruction instead of allowing the driver to generate it. As such this **needs** to be the actual property name as stored in the MongoDB document. Which is `_id`, since that is always the mapped name from `Id`.

Comment: Also the positional filtered `$[<identifier>]` syntax is not necessary for a `$push`. Since the regular "positional" match is actually on the "outer" array, then standard positional `$` will do. So the statement can be shorter without the additional logic.

Comment: Thanks, Neil.   I'll give that a try.    Are you going to submit an answer?

Comment: @NeilLunn _ iswtched from `Id` to `_id` and it worked just like you said.   I'm not sure what you mean about the `$[q]` not being necessary since I don't see where else it says to match on that question id.   The LINQ query is for the parent quiz.